# How to send different structs in a function of a trait?

Tags: data-structures, struct, enums, rust, traits

```
enum Property {
    Triangle(TriangleProperty),
    Square(SquareProperty),
}

struct Triangle {
    x: u8,
    y: Vec<u8>,
}

struct Square {
    x: u8,
    y: String,
}

struct TriangleProperty {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
}

struct SquareProperty {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
    c: u8,
    d: u8,
}

trait Shape {
    fn do_magic(&self, p: Property) -> u64;
}

impl Shape for Triangle {
    fn do_magic(&self, p: Property) -> u64 {
        match (p) {
            Triangle(x) => { /* do something with x */ }
            _ => panic("this wont happen"),
        }
    }
}

impl Shape for Square {
    fn do_magic(&self, p: Property) -> u64 {
        match (p) {
            Square(x) => { /* do something with x */ }
            _ => panic("this wont happen"),
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm calling `panic` which i don't think is good way to deal with this.

This is just an example but I cannot have `TriangleProperty` inside the `Triangle` struct. Because I'm using `TriangleProperty` as an input in the function `do_magic` that uses a constant immutable `Triangle` struct. So the only option i can think of is wrapping in an `enum`. But is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a use case for an *associated type*:

```
trait Shape {
    type Property;
    fn do_magic(&self, p: Self::Property) -> u64;
}

impl Shape for Triangle {
    type Property = TriangleProperty;
    fn do_magic(&self, p: Self::Property) -> u64 {
        /* do something with p */
    }
}

impl Shape for Square {
    type Property = SquareProperty;
    fn do_magic(&self, p: Self::Property) -> u64 {
        /* do something with p */
    }
}
```

When you implement `Shape` you choose what type `Self::Property` will be, and within the `impl` you can use it as the concrete type. The compiler will not allow you to pass a `SquareProperty` to `Triangle::do_magic` or vice versa.